# Php date_diff

Tags: php

почему в этом коде на выходе результат такой?

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2014-03-01');
$datetime2 = date_create('2014-03-31');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%Y %m %d'); 
----
00 1 2
----
```

Откуда взялось 2 дня?

немного изменим начальную дату:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2014-03-02');
$datetime2 = date_create('2014-03-31');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%Y %m %d'); 
----
00 0 29
----
```

прибавился всего +1 день, и уже не 1мес и 2 дня, а 0 мес и 29дней...

Comment: Посмотрите на результат выполнения вашего кода: http://ideone.com/TLjUlJ  
Единственное, что могу посоветовать, это попробовать написать так:  

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2, true);  

К тому же, у вас взялось не 2, а 3 лишних дня.

Comment: добавлял true, ничего интересно не вышло.

кстати если указать дату например 2014-01-01 и 2014-02-01 то получим ровно 0 лет 1 мес и 0 дней. все остальные даты получаются криво...

2014-03-01 и 2014-04-01 = 0год 1мес 2дня
2014-03-01 и 2014-04-02 = 0год 1мес 1дня ...

ёпт ну вот как так может быть? ))

Comment: Поведение действительно странное. Например, для тех же чисел января получим корректное значение `00 0 30`. А если сменить, timezone, например, на 'America/New_York', приведенный код начинает считаться корректно.

Как вариант решения получайте количество дней

    $interval->format('%a');

и уже обрабатывать полученное значение самостоятельно

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, мне удалось докопаться до истины. Думаю, этот код пояснит причину (часовой пояс выставлен как Europe/Moscow)

```
$sourceDate = strtotime('2014-03-01');
echo date('Y-m-d', $sourceDate),"\n"; // 2014-03-01
echo gmdate('Y-m-d', $sourceDate),"\n"; // 2014-02-28

$sourceDate = strtotime('2014-03-31');
echo date('Y-m-d', $sourceDate),"\n"; // 2014-03-31
echo gmdate('Y-m-d', $sourceDate),"\n"; // 2014-03-30
```

Наращивание даты идет в UTC. [Вот пример реализации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475646/undefined-date-diff) date_diff на php:

```
function date_diff($date1, $date2) { 
    $current = $date1; 
    $datetime2 = date_create($date2); 
    $count = 0; 
    while(date_create($current) < $datetime2){ 
        $current = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current))); 
        $count++; 
    }
    return $count; 
}
```

Поэтому как решение проблемы можно изменить код на такой:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2014-03-01 00:00:00 +00');
$datetime2 = date_create('2014-03-31 00:00:00 +00');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%Y %m %d');
```

И получим корректную разницу

Comment: спасибо. Но есть баги ((

например даты: 2014-03-01 и 2014-05-01, выдает результат 0 1 30,  получается прошло не 2 месяца , а 1 месяц и 30 дней, что есть не правильно. Получается, мне нужно делать цикл и узнавать сколько дней в месяце для моих интервалов дат ((

Comment: @тест, поправил решение